# What does a file damaged by loss of write-behind caching look like?

Tags: file-corruption

I use an app called WinLESS to compile .less files to .css. Quite a few times over the years it's given me a warning that the settings are corrupt and refuses to launch. Normally I just delete the config file and set everything up all over again. The most recent time this happened, I was irked enough by it to I decided to take a look in the file;

It's an XML file, typically about 44kb long and this was no exception - same size. It had a few regular bytes one might expect to find in an xml file; `<?xml ...` but then the majority (99%+) of the tail of the file was just a long block of 0x00 bytes. I figured one day I'd get round to doing something with a filesystemwatcher to keep a backup of the file whenever it changed so I could just restore it automatically, and put it down to a bug in winless screwing up when saving its settings on exit

Just now I had the exact same problem with SourceTree - again an app that keeps settings in an XML file. I opened it up to take a look and the same kind of problem manifest - a 12kb file but the XML data ceases after a few hundred bytes and the remainder of the file is 0x00

It's puzzled me enough to ask a Q about it; the only significant event from today is that SourceTree was running when I went out, I forgot to sleep the laptop, it ran out of battery (and doesn't hibernate/sleep itself - it just abruptly powers down), and game over

Is the data corruption causes by abrupt power loss and is a windows/disk/io/cache subsystem related problem, or given that both these apps use XML files, is it indicative of an XML/file writing strategy where some XML component preallocates all the bytes necessary for the file but never finishes writing them?

I guess my question in essence is "for what reason might a file be the right size but full of trailing zero bytes, rather than just stopping (being end-of-file) at the point that writing ceased?"

Answer (score 0):

You should run chkdsk and look at the System Event log for NTFS errors.

The file system will be mounted and used after a crash normally. If you write a lot of data after the crash you can corrupt your volume tables in a bad way.

During the second boot after the crash Windows will not mount the volume and then repair everything but that might be already too late and you end up with mixed file contents.

Zeros can also happen although I have seen NTFS corruptions with mixed fiile contents from other files where an xml file did get in the middle binary data from Windows Defender pattern files. The offset is a pretty good pattern if it is a multiple of 4K then it can be an NTFS corruption or the application did just use a 4 KB buffer which is e.g. for StreamWriter also the case.